# Same Paypal account in different websites with wooCommerce using Paypal Standard - IPN issues

Tags: woocommerce, paypal-ipn

Hi I'm using the same Paypal account in different websites with wooCommerce using Paypal Standard and one of them has IPN issues. I have received this email:

---

Hello, XXX

Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment Notifications (IPN). IPNs sent to the following URL(s) failed:

https://mywebsitedomain/wc-api/WC_Gateway_Paypal/

If you don't recognise this URL, you may be using a service provider that is using IPN on your behalf. Please contact your service provider with the above information. If this problem continues, IPNs may be disabled for your account.

---

It was working a couple of weeks ago. Now it is working just in one website which has the same configuration, plugins etc. The issue is that my orders are not changing to complete in one of the websites.

Where can I find some logs? What am I missing? Is it possible to have same account in multiple websites or it is deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use the same account in multiple websites. But if using an integration that depends on IPN, that website needs to be able to receive IPN messages. Review your account's IPN history in https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history , and correct any problems with your server that are preventing it from receiving or preventing it from responding with an HTTP 200 success status. One example would be if it is configured with the wrong email address and hence does not accept the IPN messages it receives.

You can also try a newer or different WooCommerce PayPal plugin that does not depend on IPN. https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-checkout/ might be one of them, otherwise try some other one (there are many)

Comment: Thanks Preston, I checked the history and I have HTTP Response code. and the Delivery status is Retrying. Check with my hosting about any paypal ip blocks and nothing. Is there any other way to check this error logs? I can't find anything on the server. =(

Comment: Did you mean to say _no_ response code? Well, if your server is unreachable it's unreachable. Ensure you're using a standard HTTPS port (443), that it is open, and try with a different domain or direct IP if necessary. You can also test IPN messages using the simulator on developer.paypal.com